# Drop infrequent values in column

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with ID and category and a number of flags following.
When I run this

```
df['category'].value_counts().tail(15)
```

I see that a dozen of them are occurring less than 7 times.
So I want to delete the rows with these categories from the dataframe.

I wanted to run something like this but it gives me error:

```
df.drop(df[df.category.value_counts() < 7].index, inplace=True)
```

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

How do I drop those rows from the dataframe which categories happen less than 7 times?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df = df[df.groupby('category')['category'].transform('count')>=7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `isin` here:

```
counts = df.category.value_counts()

# or
# to_drop = counts.tail(15).index
to_drop = counts[counts < 7].index

df = df[~df['category'].isin(to_drop)]
```